# Why can't I unbind this service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, sendgrid, appdirect

When I try to unbind a specific SendGrid service from my Java Liberty application running on Bluemix, I get the following error message:

> Service broker error: {"description"=>"Received exception with class 'javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException' and message 'Problem with reading the data, class com.appdirect.backend.integration.custom.sendgrid.output.SendGridResult, ContentType: application/xml;charset=utf-8.' while calling integration endpoint 'null'."}

I get the same message using the Bluemix gui and cf cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go [here](http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport) and open a support ticket. This isn't something you can address on your end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an error with the broker and SendGrid.  Can you try deleting your app as well then try to delete the service?

Comment: I get the same message when trying to delete the app/service

Answer (score 1):

I can recreate this problem; you're not doing anything wrong. It's an operational problem with the Sendgrid service broker that they need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are some issues deleting specific service instances like that of mysql community service instance. Raise a support ticket at https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp/ , the support team would help with deleting of the service instances from your org/space. Ensure you provide the details of your service, space and org while opening the service ticket.